# how to check array has map key exists or not in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
json_array = [{"id":82,"access_token":"3d04ba958abffbbb69f79dd2e108729e"}]

if json_array[0].key?(:access_token)
 return true
else
 return false
end
```

Every time return false

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails, it should work just fine, if this is pure ruby then you need to be exact about the type of key,

in ruby `json_array[0].key?(:access_token)` will return false because the key is a string type in your json array and you are checking if the key exists as a symbol, so to make it work in your case you'll need

```
return json_array.first.key?("access_token")
```

you don't need to do if then to return true or false in this case, you can just return the result of the key check

This works in rails because with [action controller parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) you can use either string or symbol representation to access the hash elements.

Hope this helps

Comment: `json_array` is not a "HashWithIndifferentAccess". It's also not JSON; it's a Ruby array of hashes where the keys are symbols, because `"id":82` is a shortcut for `:"id" => 82`, and `:"id"` is a symbol. The OP should try `json_array.dig(0, :access_token)`

Answer (score 0):

It returns false because `"access_token"` is not the same as `:access_token`.

Try checking for the key `"access_token"` instead.